# logging permission in laravel

Tags: laravel, logging

As mentioned in laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging i used permission in logging.php configuration as follows

```
'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'tap' => [App\Providers\JsonFormatter::class],
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'permission' => 0777,
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'tap' => [App\Providers\JsonFormatter::class],
            'path' => storage_path('logs/'.php_sapi_name().'/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'permission' => 0777,
            'days' => 1,
        ],
```

then I deleted all previous logs and then stored then logs again but every linked directory has **drwxr-xr-x** these permissions. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did  you apply 644 to the storage directory?

Comment: @HéctorWilliam I don't think so, I deleted all directories and did nothing permission wise

Comment: I think that may be the problem, try to  give permission to the folder ``chmod 644 storage -Rf``, additionally here you can check detailed recommendations to set things properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel